# How concurrent are CQL's collections?

Tags: cassandra

I am taking a look at Cassandra's CQL collections (list, set, map) and I can't find a reliable source stating on their concurrency.

I want to know if having multiple writers adding different elements to the same set is supported.

From what I read of the implementation (http://www.opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/07/24/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure-sets-lists-and-maps/) it seems that sets are implemented using columns, so I should be safe.

But on the other hand, I've read here and there that the operations on the collections always triggered a full read (even writes). This suggests that I could get in trouble if multiple writers were using the same collection.

So can I (and should I) use collection from multiple writers? (And also, the documentation mentions that collections should be used for *"small amount of data"*, how much would that be? Tens, hundreds, thousands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates are atomic which should include any collections in the row. So it should be fine to have multiple writers.

"In an UPDATE statement, all updates within the same partition key are applied atomically and in isolation."

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#updateStmt

"Values of items in collections are limited to 64K"

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/ddl/ddlWhenCollections.html

Cheers,

Comment: I guess that apply to all data types no matter how they are implemented, I need to stop thinking in Thrift. As for the length, I know the limitation of 64K per elements and 64K elements, but there is quite a difference between "small amount of data" and 64K elements :/

Comment: I ended up not using collections for my problem. It seems that if you come to ask yourself "Is this too big for collections?" it probably is.

Comment: I think the best use case for CQL collections is for those that have a relatively fixed size and are not at risk of being unbounded. All the best with your project.